# Why is the ASTER GDEM called digital elevation "model"?

Tags: raster, dem

The ASTER GDEM provides the elevation data for a region on the earth surface. Why is it called digital elevation "model", but not "data" or "observation"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a digital elevation "model", because it is just that, a model. The ASTER GDEM elevation values aren't direct measurements. They are derived using a photogrammetric technique known as stereo correlation.

From the ASTER GDEM v003 [Description](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/astgtmv003/):

> The ASTER GDEM Version 3 data product was created from the automated processing of the entire ASTER Level 1A archive of scenes acquired between March 1, 2000, and November 30, 2013. Stereo correlation was used to produce over one million individual scene based ASTER DEMs, to which cloud masking was applied. All cloud screened DEMs and non-cloud screened DEMs were stacked. Residual bad values and outliers were removed. In areas with limited data stacking, several existing reference DEMs were used to supplement ASTER data to correct for residual anomalies. Selected data were averaged to create final pixel values before partitioning the data into 1° by 1° tiles with a one pixel overlap.

See also:

- Abrams *et. al* (2020) ASTER Global Digital Elevation Model (GDEM) and ASTER Global Water Body Dataset (ASTWBD), Remote Sens. 12, 1156; [doi:10.3390/rs12071156](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/12/7/1156)